# LanguageType field autocomplete in symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to have languageType field autocomplete in symfony 3.2. 
I did an atempt to integrate chosen jquery library but without result

So i dowloaded the library and i copied it into web/ of my project , also i added the script in layout twig .

Some one could help me to combine chosen libary (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) into LanguageType attributes in order to LanguageType field will be Autocomplete.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to answer your question, since you didn't provide any technical details of your problem. Read more here about how to ask question properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add to the question the code you tried and explain what does not worked.